# Parsing command line arguments

Tags: f#

Usage:

---

```
// Usage: dndgenerate /e [emhd] [0-9+]
//          dndgenerate /e d 4 4 5 4
// /e   Generate Encounter. Parameter can be one of
//          e - Easy
//          m - Medium
//          h - Hard
//          d - Deadly
//      As well as a list of heroes by their levels
//
// Example:  dndgenerate /e m 4 4 5 4
//      Generate a medium encounter for three level 4 and one level 5 adventurers.
```

The code to make it happen:

---

```
type DifficultyOption = Easy | Medium | Hard | Deadly

type EncounterOptions = {
    difficulty: DifficultyOption option
    heroes: int list
}

let (|Level|_|) (str: string) =
    let mutable intValue = 0

    if System.Int32.TryParse(str, &intValue)
        then match intValue with
             | x when x < 0 -> None
             | x when x > 20 -> None
             | x -> Some x
        else None



let (|Difficulty|_|) (str: string) =
    match str with
    | "e" | "E" -> Some(Easy)
    | "m" | "M" -> Some(Medium)
    | "h" | "H" -> Some(Hard)
    | "d" | "D" -> Some(Deadly)
    | x -> None

let isComplete (options:EncounterOptions) =
    not <| options.heroes.IsEmpty && options.difficulty.IsSome

type VerboseOption = VerboseOutput | TerseOutput

type MiscOptions = {
    verbose: VerboseOption
}

type GeneratorType =
    | E of EncounterOptions
    | Unknown

type ParseMode = TopLevel | Encounter | Plot | Dungeon | Settlement | Error

type CommandLineOptions = {
    misc: MiscOptions
    parseMode: ParseMode
    generatorType: GeneratorType
}

let parseTopLevel arg miscSoFar =
    match arg with
    | "/v" ->
        let newMiscSoFar = { miscSoFar with verbose = VerboseOutput }
        { misc = newMiscSoFar; parseMode = TopLevel; generatorType = Unknown }

    | "/e" -> 
        { misc = miscSoFar; parseMode = Encounter; generatorType = E { difficulty = None; heroes = [] } }

    | x ->
        { misc = miscSoFar; parseMode = Error; generatorType = Unknown }

let parseEncounter arg miscSoFar encounterGenerator =
    match arg with
    | Level x ->
        let builder' = { encounterGenerator with heroes = x :: encounterGenerator.heroes }
        { misc = miscSoFar; parseMode = Encounter; generatorType = E builder' }

    | Difficulty x ->
        let builder' = { encounterGenerator with difficulty = Some x }
        { misc = miscSoFar; parseMode = Encounter; generatorType = E builder' }

    | _ -> 
        { misc = miscSoFar; parseMode = Error; generatorType = E encounterGenerator }

let foldFunction state element =
    match state with
    | { misc = m; parseMode = TopLevel } ->
        parseTopLevel element m

    | { misc = m; parseMode = Encounter; generatorType = E(g) } ->
        parseEncounter element m g

    | { parseMode = Error } ->
        state

    | { misc = m; parseMode = p; generatorType = g } -> 
        printfn "Unexpected constellation of %A %A %A" m p g
        state

let disableIfIncomplete commandLineOptions =
    match commandLineOptions.parseMode with
    | Error ->
        commandLineOptions

    | _ ->
        match commandLineOptions.generatorType with
        | E(encounter) when isComplete encounter ->
            commandLineOptions

        | Unknown -> commandLineOptions

        | _ -> { commandLineOptions with parseMode = Error }

let parseCommandLine args =
    let defaultOptions = { 
        verbose = TerseOutput
    }

    let initialFoldState =
        { misc = defaultOptions; parseMode = TopLevel; generatorType = Unknown }

    let finalFoldState = args |> List.fold foldFunction initialFoldState

    disableIfIncomplete finalFoldState
```

Based on code from Scott Wlaschin's [Parsing command line arguments](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/pattern-matching-command-line/) but extended to include argument groups and error handling. Purposefully avoided FParsec because I'm new to F# and wanted to solve it vanilla-style first.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to F#, so I have just 2 small annotations:

The function that parses the string to Int32 can be simplified:

```
match System.Int32.TryParse(str) with
    | (true, x) when x >= 0 && x <= 20 -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```

The last case of the function `parseTopLevel` should be `_ ->` instead of `x ->` because the value is not used ('_' expresses exactly that)